# Need to decode this one line {$HOSTNAME^^} == {$arrName^^}

Tags: linux, shell-script

Following is a part from a shell script written by someone in my organization.

```
while read -r line
do
    #split if needed
    arrName=$(echo $line | cut -d"." -f1)
    if [ {$HOSTNAME^^} == {$arrName^^} ]; then
        echo "Perfect $arrName"
        echo "$1" >> $TEMPFILE
    fi
done < compuetrnames.txt
```

The entire script was understandable for me except this one line

```
if [ {$HOSTNAME^^} == {$arrName^^} ]; then
```

Can someone help me understand this line.

Comment: You can search `^^` here https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Answer (score 2):

`${variable^^}` is a Bash 4.x parameter expansion which yields the variable's value converted to uppercase.

The dollar sign needs to go before the opening brace, not after.

The (improperly quoted) `echo | cut` pipeline could similarly be written with a parameter expansion `${line%%.*}`; or you could use `while IFS='.' read line _; do`... to split the input on the first full stop immediately when you read it.

Answer (score 2):

The `${parameter^^pattern}` substitution in Bash will change the case of the characters in `$parameter` that matches the globbing pattern `pattern` to upper-case.

With no pattern, it changes the case of all characters in `$parameter`.

As tripleee pointed out in his answer, `{$...}` is a syntax error, or rather, `{$HOSTNAME^^}` will expand to the string `{hostname^^}` if your `$HOSTNAME` value is `hostname`.